# jQuery/AJAX - nested functions. Clone & Cufon

Tags: jquery, ajax, clone, cufon

I'm using Cufon, it's a very simple script changing fonts into canvas.

This code changes H1 headers:

```
 Cufon.replace('h1', { fontFamily: 'SuperMegaArial2010' });
```

Everything works fine, but I'm cloning a set of items (a few lists with headers in them):

```
jQuery('ul.myList').clone();
```

And the cufon font replacement doesn't work for the cloned items.

How to change that? Why does it happen?

[edit]

Ok, it's going to be complicated. I'm cloning my list so it will work as a second list for [Quicksand](http://razorjack.net/quicksand/). And it works, but Cufon doesn't.

```
jQuery('document').ready(function(){    
    //create a clone of the full list of elements and extract 'li' elements
    //in order to use it as the 'second' list for quicksand
        var cache_list = jQuery('ul.myList').clone();
        //Add on click event handler to the 'Show Everything' button

        jQuery('ul.myList li a[data-value=Everything]').click(function(e) {
            //Call quicksand on the original works_list list(the one visible to the user)
            //pass to it all the 'li' elements from the cached clone 
                //since we want to display them all
                jQuery('.myList').quicksand( cache_list.find('li'), {
                        duration: 500,
                        });

        jQuery('ul.myList li a[data-value=funny]').click(function(e) {
               jQuery('.myList').quicksand( cache_list.find('li[data-value=funny]'), {
                  duration: 500,
                });
                e.preventDefault();
        });    
});
```

This code is being executed long time after Cufon, I've tried adding cufon replace js code once again in the same file before the code above, but didn't help.

Comment: The example javascript doesn't make sense. What do you do with the cloned elements? You should have something like: `jQuery('ul.myList).clone().appendTo('myDiv');`. Please show us the exact code.

Comment: By the way, "H1" is a BLOCK-level element and as such should not occur in an unordered list. Maybe this has something to do with the problem. Block structuring elements include paragraphs, lists, and block quotes must not contain heading elements (h1 ... h6), but they may contain phrase markup, and in some cases, they may be nested.

Comment: @Neil I believe you're wrong, I can put almost anything between li tags? And I'm sure there's nothing wrong with that, my site is validated by w3c validator and there are no problems. I'm going to explain more about my case in the first post within minutes.

Comment: The info I gave above about H1 tags not strictly being allowed in lists comes from the webpage: `http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/html-spec/html-spec_5.html` so I would expect it to be "

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you cloned the items after your cufon call. This is because when cufon is called your items don't exist. You could simply call cufon again for it to do it's magic.

Comment: Could you post some code? Off the top of my head it could be the selector or the sequence.  Unless its a known issue.

Comment: You say `This code is being executed long time after Cufon`. Cufon needs to be called after all this code has been executed. Put it after this code block and see.